# Phaser 3 Game, Want To Resize GameObject Rectangles On Screen Resize

Tags: resize, phaser-framework

I am trying to resize some rectangles on screen on a screen resize. I am using Phaser 3.60 along with Tailwind CSS 3, and want to match the Tailwind breakpoints inside of my Phaser code. So for example, at 1536px wide and above, I would like the rectangle to be 300px by 300px. As I make the screen smaller, I would like the size of the rectangle to change, based on the screen size breakpoint? For example, at screen size below 1280px, the rectangle changes to screen size 150px by 150px. Here is my code:

```
import SudokuGameObjects from "./Classes/SudokuGameObjects";

const gameCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
gameCanvas.id = 'gameCanvas';
gameCanvas.classList.add("w-full", "h-full", "mx-auto", "m-0");

const config = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    transparent: true,
    canvas: document.getElementById("gameCanvasContainer").appendChild(gameCanvas),
    scale: {
        zoom: 1,
        mode: Phaser.Scale.RESIZE,
    },
    scene: [SudokuGameObjects],
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 300 }
        }
    },
    render: {
        pixelArt: false,
        roundPixels: true
    },
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
let sudokuScene = game.scene.keys.SudokuGameObjects;

window.addEventListener('load', () => 
{
    window.addEventListener('resize', event => 
    {
        sudokuScene.resizeGameObject();
    });
});
```

And my SudokuGameObjects file:

```
export default class SudokuGameObjects extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor() 
    {
        super({key: 'SudokuGameObjects', active: true});

        this.box;
    }

    resizeGameObject()
    {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");

        if(canvas.style.width > 1536)
        {
            this.box.setSize(300, 300);
        }

        if(canvas.style.width < 1280)
        {
            this.box.setSize(150, 150);
        }
    }

    create() 
    {
        this.box = this.add.rectangle(300, 200, 100, 100, "0xff0000").setOrigin(0.5);
        this.box.setDisplaySize(300, 300);
        this.box = this.add.text(300, 200, 1, { fontFamily: 'Figtree', fontSize: 32, color: "0xffffff", stroke: "0xffffff", strokeThickness: 1, }).setOrigin(0.5); 
    }
}
```

In my browser console, I get an error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sudokuScene.resizeGameObject')
```

Could this be because my scene has yet to be loaded?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right the scene needs abit of time to load, you could get the scene in your event listener, or use the whole chain `game.scene.keys.SudokuGameObjects.resizeGameObject()`.

**Small demo:**
*I would use the function `getScenes` since it gets the active scene, just to be on the save side([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.SceneManager.html))*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

let isSimulatedBig = true;

document.querySelector('#change').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let currentScene = game.scene.getScenes()[0];
    currentScene.resizeGameObject();
    isSimulatedBig = !isSimulatedBig;
});

class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('TestScene');
    }
    
    create () {
        this.add.text(10,10, 'DEMO TEXT')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        this.box = this.add.rectangle(250, 90, 100, 100, "0xff0000").setOrigin(0.5);
    }

    resizeGameObject() {

        if(isSimulatedBig){
            this.box.setSize(150, 150);
        }

        if(!isSimulatedBig){
            this.box.setSize(50, 50);
        }
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: TestScene,
}; 

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-family:Arial">Click to simulate Size Change</span>
<br/>
<button id="change"> Toogle Size Change </button><br/>
<br/>
```

> **Side note:** Nevertheless if you are looking into resizing the canvas / phaser-game, it might be better to use the Phaser Scalemanager. ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scale.ScaleManager.html), [link to official examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/scalemanager))